# n= 29, p value for three tests: .061, .09 and .13 but all trending in predicted direction: How to report?

Tags: paired-data

So I ran three paired samples t-tests to see if people did a certain action more after hearing a target stimulus. my prediction is that they would do the action more. All tests were one-tailed as i was only looking at one direction: did it increase after x.
n = 29 for each test.

the p values for tests were, First test:.061, one-tailed, Second test:p = .098, one-tailed and third test: p = .13, one-tailed. But in every result the mean *was* higher in the group I predicted would be higher after the stimulus.

So, when I report this what can I say? Should I say that while not 'significant' they were in the 'expected direction' and that repeating the test with a larger sample is needed? In other words that there is an interesting trend and deserves more investigation?

Thanks so much!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the three tests reported a strength of evidence in the data against their respective nulls that might reasonably be described as 'weak', 'very weak', and 'trivial'. Don't lose sight of the fact that a p-value of 0.05 reflects weak evidence against the null according to the statistical model of the test.

Comment: If the investigation is of interest then you need to perform a fresh experiment...

Comment: @MichaelLew So when I report this, should I saw as mean was always higher in the group that saw the stimulus this is interesting and that future research is warranted even though results are weak/trivial?

Comment: You can describe the results (including effect size and some scale for important size), but also explain in detail the experiment and sampling procedures (e.g. did you use a random number generator for randomisation of treatments/subjects?). Do not claim 'significance' or 'near significance' as those terms have no reliable meaning. Perhaps read this, paying attention to figures 1–3 and 8: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286